# Componente de Input não está alterando o valor do state

Tags: react, typescript, react-native

Tenho um componente de Input que é um Wrapper do TextInput (react-native).
Quando digito o valor no meu componente Input e depois tento mostrar o valor da variável a qual o texto deveria ter sido atribuído, a variável aparece com o valor que ela foi criada, não sofrendo alteração.

```js
// MyInput
import React from 'react';
import { TextInput, Text } from 'react-native';

import styles from './styles';

interface InputProps {
  label: String,
  placeholder: String,
  onChangeText: Function,
  defaultValue?: String,
  value: String,
}

const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = ({ label }: InputProps, ...props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Text style={styles.label}>{label}</Text>
      <TextInput { ...props } style={styles.input}/>
    </>
  );
}

export default Input;
```

E a tela onde faço a chamada do componente:

```js
// login
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Input from '../../components/Input';

import { View, ImageBackground, Text, Image, Alert, Button } from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';
import BackgroundLogin from '../../assets/images/BackGroundBanner01.png';

interface UserProps {
  email: String,
  password: String,
}

function Login() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<UserProps> ({email: 'default', password: ''});
  return (
    <ImageBackground source={BackgroundLogin} style={styles.container}>
      <Input value={user.email} onChangeText={(text: String) => setUser({...user, email: text})} label="Email"></Input>
      <Button
      onPress={() => Alert.alert(`${user.email}`)}
      title="Testar"
      />
    </ImageBackground>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Quando informo texto "Hello" no Input, e pressiono o botão de testar, a aplicação me retorna "default" que é o valor inicial que a variável foi instanciada.

Se eu remover o Wrapper e deixar direto o TextInput, o código funciona sem problemas.

> Citação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, isso aconteceu por causa que no seu wrapper você declarou:

```
...
const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = ({ label }: InputProps, ...props) => {
...
}
```

A sintaxe correta seria:

```
...
const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = ({ label,  ...props }) => {
...
}
```

Todas as props recebidas em um componente são guardadas no primeiro argumento do component. Também como pode ver eu não declarei a interface de props novamente, mas se você não passará children para esse componente não há necessidade de usar o React.FC pois ele declara tipos que você não utilizará, nesse caso ficaria assim:
A sintaxe correta seria:

```
...
const Input = ({ label,  ...props }: InputProps) => {
...
}
```

Uma curiosidade: o segundo argumento pode ser o context, mas ele estará indefinido, ao não ser que você defina o contextTypes para o componente, dessa forma:

```
const Input = (props, context) => {
  // esse context geralmente é utilizado junto ao redux-i18n (i18n: seu site estar disponível em vários idiomas)
  return (
   <span>{context.t('alguma-string')}</span>
  )
}

Input.contextTypes = {
    t: PropTypes.func
}
```

Mas claro isso não é muito utilizado devido a hook `useContext`.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Se eu fizer desta forma ````const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = ({ label,  ...props }) => { ````o componente TextInput apresenta esse erro "No overload matches this call.". conforme essa imagem: https://ibb.co/BKZ2yFz

Comment: Sim esqueci de falar sobre isso, isso é um erro de typescript, você deve pegar a interface de props do componente TextField e estender com a sua interface de props que tem o label

Answer (score 1):

Como você utilizou o *template* [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) para codificar e no componente `TextInput` utilizado no seu projeto tem os tipos definidos que é `Readonly<TextInputProps>` que no caso particular pode ser feito uma extensão para colocar tipos diferentes a mais em seu componente personalizado, o exemplo claro é dessa `interface`:

```
interface Props extends Readonly<TextInputProps> {
  label: string;
}
```

Na interface `Props` agora além das propriedades do componente `TextInput` referida no `Readonly<TextInputProps>` tem uma `label` do tipo `string` (o tipo é sempre com o `s` minúsculo, e isso tem diferença do S em maiúsculo) e a partir desse contrato pode ser criado um modelo mais enxuto desse componente:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { TextInput, Text, TextInputProps } from 'react-native';

interface Props extends Readonly<TextInputProps> {
  label: string;
}

const Input: React.FC<Props> = ({label, ...shared}: Props) => {    
  return (
    <>    
      <Text>{label}</Text>
      <TextInput { ...shared } />                  
    </>
  )
}

export default Input;
```

observando que `label` é separado de `shared` separando as propriedades e isso é repassado integramente ao componente em especifico.

Na utilização do componente fica mais simples e legível utilizando somente as propriedades que são obrigatórias:

```
<Input label="Input" 
    value={user.email} 
    onChangeText={(text: string) => setUser({...user, email: text})}
/>
```

e nesse caso o seu componente vai funcionar como deveria, pois não quebra os tipos das propriedades do componente como estava acontecendo.